# Grid Item doesn't span across rows after wrapping it in link

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

for the longest time I did avoid html/CSS till now. To get started I wanted to build a simple CSS grid website. 3 items in the grid. All works well and looks as I wanted it to be. Like this:

[image: grid works]

But I wanted to use the whole Aside-Items as a Hyperlink. So I wrapped a `href=` around it but then the same CSS looks like this.

[image: after inserting a link]

Questions:

1. How can I have the look from picture one with the functionality that the `"Aside-GridItem"` is a Hyperlink?
2. Is this a okay way? Or do I get problems with SEO for `"hiddin"` the link with text-decoration : none?

Here my code:

```css
.gridwrapper{
  display:grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  background-color: wheat;
  gap: 5px;
}

.gridHeader{
  background-color:blueviolet;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;

  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.gridContent{
  background-color:blue;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;

  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.gridAside{
  background-color:goldenrod;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;

  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>BlazorFK</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="gridwrapper">
  <div class="gridHeader">HEADER</div>
  <div class="gridContent">...content...</div>
  <a href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <div class="gridAside">Aside</div>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
<script></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes great. Should have asked earlyer :) I have tried lots of stuff but not this! Would you consider this bad that I use text-decoration : none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this class `class="gridAside"` to the parent link so that will be

> `<a class="gridAside" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">`

### Example

```css
.gridwrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  background-color: wheat;
  gap: 5px;
}

.gridHeader {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.gridContent {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.gridAside {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 1em;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>BlazorFK</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gridwrapper">
    <div class="gridHeader">HEADER</div>
    <div class="gridContent">...content...</div>
    <a class="gridAside" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <div>Aside</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```